# Include css, js, html from apps in Django project, in a modular way

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have django project with several apps.  In my main html template I am including the relevant resources -- js, css in this case and those entries are coded in by hand like so:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/test.js' %}"></script>
```

I'd like to modularize this so that I can somehow loop over my projects and have their dependencies included only if they are installed/enabled.  In this way I can also add more apps in the future and not have to touch my main template.

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this?

My thought is that if I can pass each application's required resources to the main template as parameters via views.py then maybe I can loop over them (utilizing sekizai...):

```
{# Include external app resources #}
{% for app, template in installed_apps.items %}
    {% include template %}
{% endfor %}
```

And views.py would go something like:

```
external_apps = [foo, bar]
external_apps = settings.EXTERNAL_APPS # Ok, this should exist in settings already
def main(request):
    installed_apps = {}
    for app in external_apps:
        installed_apps[app] = app + "_template.html"

    template = loader.get_template('main_template.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'installed_apps': installed_apps,
        })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Then for each app I would create a template that would fill out the necessary blocks in the main template file.

This approach seems pretty rigid though and I'm wondering if there is a more common or standardized way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

base.html:

```
...
<script src="{% static 'js/test.js' %}"></script>
{% block extra_js %}{% endblock extrajs %}
...
```

In your app template:

```
{% block extra_js %}<script src="{% static 'js/myapp.js' %}"></script>{% endblock extra_js %}
```